# can not animate sibling element

Tags: css, jquery-animate, element, siblings

Well, I've got div with 3 elements in it:

```
<div> 
    <img src="http://localhost/images/4.png" alt="alt 4" class="background">
    <img src="http://localhost/images/4_icon.png" alt="alt 4" class="icon">
    <p>
        bla bla
    </p>
</div>
```

and css such as:

```
.icon:hover ~ .background {
    transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

but no idea why, it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't target a previous element with CSS.

Comment: `~` means the one how comes after and not before

Comment: even when I swap them, it still doesn't work

Comment: do you want  on hover icon the background scale?

Comment: okay my fault it does, but what to do if I want to animate previous element? is there a way without using javascript?

Comment: I want to scale background when I hover on icon

Comment: No, there is no "previous sibling" selector in css

Comment: You can solve it with flexbox/grid and the order property. p.s. Your profile pic is creepy.

Comment: okay, thank you guys

Comment: or by using js/jquery:https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the icon with the background element. The tilde only works on the next elements. See example below. The other solution would be using js.

```
<div> 
    <img src="http://localhost/images/4_icon.png" alt="alt 4" class="icon">
    <img src="http://localhost/images/4.png" alt="alt 4" class="background">
    <p>
        bla bla
    </p>
</div>
```